# Same TextInput based component behaves differently regarding height

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-textinput

I have a component that wraps a `TextInput` and has an option to display the content on multiline. However, it's used in multiple places around the app, and in some spots the multiline makes the height of the `TextInput` grow, but in others it remains the same. The weirdest thing is that it is used in the exact same screen, one below the other (as you can see below)!

```
<View style={styles.inputContainer}>
    <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={(text) => onChangeText(text)}
        value={value}
        multiline={multiline}
        keyboardType={keyboardType}
    />
</View>
```

Styling:

```
inputContainer: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      alignItems: 'center',
      borderBottomWidth: 1,
      borderBottomColor: colors.grayLighter
   },
   input: {
      color: colors.grayTextDarker,
      paddingVertical:12,
      width: '100%',
      paddingHorizontal: 20,
      fontFamily: FONTS.Arial,
      fontSize: 18,
      textAlign: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center'
   },
```

Usage of component when height is not adapted:

```
<CustomInput2
      label={'HEIGHT OF TEXTINPUT NOT RESIZING WHEN TEXT IS MULTILINE'}
      onChangeText={(value) => updateState(value)}
      value={'vjner vnrjg nvdy hf ythnf vt f mb yhb c vyh fbt j  vth yb j fv yjbd trxh vydr hbf tdfx yd yjhbtf jy'}
      multiline={true}
      keyboardType="default"
/>
```

Usage of component when height IS adapted:

```
<CustomInput2
      label={"My Label}
      onChangeText={(value) => setState(value)}
      value={"as you can see in the picture below, the height of the input resizes here"}
      multiline={true}
      keyboardType="url"
/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this behavior is caused by the `"url"` `keyboardType`, since it may not accept multiline URLs.